FirebaseAuth throws FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException for anonymous user
When I try to delete anonymous user by calling
firebaseAuth.currentUser!!.delete()

it throws FirebaseAuthRecentLoginRequiredException, but it is impossible to reauthenticate as anonymous user. According to this answear, in the past this exception was not thrown. How can I delete anonymous user?
Firebase BOM: 30.3.2

As the duplicate answers say, you have to "For anonymous users, there is no need to reauthenticate them before deleting their account". So most likely you're already authenticated with a provider that requires the user to enter credentials.

you can use auto clean
firebase

If you've upgraded your project to Firebase Authentication with
Identity Platform, you can enable automatic clean-up in the Firebase
console. When you enable this feature you allow Firebase to
automatically delete anonymous accounts older than 30 days.

